# Modifying the django admin user interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am a newbee to django i am following some video lectures. After doing exactly as per instructions am unable to add extra filed user admin interface. I am attaching modes.py and admin.py for check. Please help me

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    #Extra values
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s Profile' % self.user 

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

from django.db.models.signals import post_save

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User )
```

**Admin.py**

```
class UserProfileInLIne(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inline = (UserProfileInLIne, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Hi, 
your code looks correct, but maybe you have forgot to register your "profile" application ?

Comment: Hey thanks for response i registered the application the problem is when i am opening the user admin page bio is not showing up.

Comment: Hey Thanks,

I got answer after check multiple times.
its Typo error
Used the "inline" Instead of "inlines"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `inline` instead of `inlines`. Here you have link to django source code [ModelAdmin class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L436).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I wrote the comment before checking your answer please do not mind

Answer (score 1):

why not just save your self the trouble and use a custom user model?

[> django docs on custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

that way you have one model for writing into and only one model for when you'll be calling it in your views.

```
# settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.UserProfile'

# models.py
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    #Extra values
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)


# admin.py
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

and anywhere else you want to use user instance (ie. other models, views) just use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`